# Material UI TextField makes parent component render too much inside Formik

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Formik for my react project including:

**Wrapper component**

```
const Wrapper = ({ children, id }) => {
  console.log("re-render ", id);
  return <div>{children}</div>;
};
```

**Form component**

```
<Formik
          initialValues={{
            title: "",
            description: "",
          }}
          validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
            title: Yup.string().required("Title is required"),
            description: Yup.string().required("Description"),
          })}
          onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
            // ...submit stuff
          }}
        >
          {({ handleChange, handleSubmit, isSubmitting, values }) => (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">
              <Wrapper id="title">
                <TextField
                  variant="outlined"
                  fullWidth
                  label="title"
                  name="title"
                  margin="dense"
                  value={values.title}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
              </Wrapper>
              <Wrapper id="description">
                <TextField
                  variant="outlined"
                  fullWidth
                  label="description"
                  name="description"
                  margin="dense"
                  value={values.description}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
              </Wrapper>
              <Button
                type="submit"
              >
                Submit
              </Button>
            </form>
          )}
        </Formik>
```

The problem occurs whenever I type on **TextField** then the **Wrapper component** render so much times even other wrapper components not contained the typing textfield also render too

In my real project, the Wrapper component is more complex than the sample code and it makes the textfield so laggy

How I can resolve this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to use a custom component for every TextField and we just update the state in formik at **onBlur**:

**CustomTextField component**

```
const CustomTextField = ({ setFieldValue, name, fieldName, type, label, initialValue }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
  const handleChange = (e) => setValue(e.target.value);
  const handleBlur = () => setFieldValue(fieldName, value);
  return (
    <TextField
      variant="outlined"
      fullWidth
      type={type}
      label={label}
      name={name}
      margin="dense"
      value={value}
      onChange={handleChange}
      onBlur={handleBlur}
    />
  );
};
```

**Form component**

```
<Formik
    initialValues={{
        title: "",
        description: "",
    }}
    validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
        title: Yup.string().required("Title is required"),
        description: Yup.string().required("Description"),
    })}
    onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
        // ...submit stuff
    }}
>
    {({ handleChange, handleSubmit, isSubmitting, values, setFieldValue }) => (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">
        <Wrapper id="title">
            <CustomTextField
                type="text"
                label="title"
                name="title"
                fieldName="title"
                setFieldValue={setFieldValue}
                initialValue={values.title}
            />
        </Wrapper>
        <Wrapper id="description">
            <CustomTextField
                type="text"
                label="description"
                name="description"
                fieldName="description"
                setFieldValue={setFieldValue}
                initialValue={values.description}
            />
        </Wrapper>
        <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
    </form>
    )}
</Formik>
```